# Confusing null reference exception in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm running a program daily which goes to an API, fetches a bunch of weather data in JSON form and stores it in a database. It's worked fine for months, but since yesterday, it's been failing. I'm trying to debug and can't figure out what's going on. I get a valid response, in the same format as before, and logging it in the console or looking at it in a breakpoint, it seems fine. However, I'm getting this exception:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform
>   runtime binding on a null reference
>          at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
>          at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite
>   site, T0 arg0)
>          at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
>          at DbMgr.DarkSky.d__9.MoveNext() in C:\Users\BaruchKogan\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects
>       \DbMgr\DbMgr\DarkSky.cs:line 434
>       pausedSystem.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException
>       : Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference
>          at DbMgr.DarkSky.d__9.MoveNext() in C:\Users\BaruchKogan\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects
>       \DbMgr\DbMgr\DarkSky.cs:line 461
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
>          at DbMgr.DarkSky.d__6.MoveNext() in C:\Users\BaruchKogan\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\DbMgr\DbMgr
>       \DarkSky.cs:line 205
>       ---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform
>   runtime binding on a nul
>       l reference
>          at DbMgr.DarkSky.d__9.MoveNext() in C:\Users\BaruchKogan\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects
>       \DbMgr\DbMgr\DarkSky.cs:line 461<---

The offending code is here:

```
Console.WriteLine(responseJson.daily.data[0]);
JObject darkSkyDaily = responseJson.daily.data[0];
if (DailyBreakdown(darkSkyDaily, plot, blobUri, false).Result != 0)
{
    JArray darkSkyHourlies = responseJson.hourly.data;
    if (darkSkyHourlies.Count > 0)
    {
       foreach (JObject item in darkSkyHourlies)
        {
            await HourlyBreakdown(item, plot.ID, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Line 435 is the first line, which runs fine, and writes a valid object string to the console.

DailyBreakdown() is returning 0 in this particular case because this daily is already in the database.

```
static async Task<int> DailyBreakdown(JObject daily, GeographicalPlot plot, String blobUri, Boolean isForecast)
        {
            using (var newEntities = new atpLabsDbEntities1())
            {
                try
                {
                    DateTime dailyTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds(Convert.ToDouble((int)daily["time"]));
                    var testDailies = from c in newEntities.WeatherDailies
                                      where c.GeographicalPlotID == plot.ID && c.Time == dailyTime
                                      select c;
                    if ((testDailies.Count() == 0) || (isForecast == true))
                    {
                        string summary = (string)daily["summary"];
                        int sunsetTime = (int)daily["sunsetTime"];
                        int sunriseTime = (int)daily["sunriseTime"];
                        double? moonPhase = (double?)daily["moonPhase"];
                        string precipType = (string)daily["precipType"];
                        double? temperatureMin = (double?)daily["temperatureMin"];
                        double? temperatureMax = (double?)daily["temperatureMax"];
                        double? apparentTemperatureMin = (double?)daily["apparentTemperatureMin"];
                        double? apparentTemperatureMax = (double?)daily["apparentTemperatureMax"];
                        int temperatureMinTime = (int)daily["temperatureMinTime"];
                        int temperatureMaxTime = (int)daily["temperatureMaxTime"];
                        int apparentTemperatureMinTime = (int)daily["apparentTemperatureMinTime"];
                        int apparentTemperatureMaxTime = (int)daily["apparentTemperatureMaxTime"];
                        double? dewPoint = (double?)daily["dewPoint"];
                        double? humidity = (double?)daily["humidity"];
                        double? windSpeed = (double?)daily["windSpeed"];
                        double? windBearing = (double?)daily["windBearing"];
                        double? visibility = (double?)daily["visibility"];
                        double? cloudCover = (double?)daily["cloudCover"];
                        double? pressure = (double?)daily["pressure"];
                        dynamic newWeatherDaily;
                        if (isForecast == true)
                        {
                            newWeatherDaily = new WeatherDailyForecast();
                            newWeatherDaily.ForecastTime = DateTime.Now;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            newWeatherDaily = new WeatherDaily();
                        }
                        newWeatherDaily.GeographicalPlotID = plot.ID;
                        newWeatherDaily.Time = dailyTime;
                        newWeatherDaily.Summary = summary;
                        newWeatherDaily.SunriseTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(sunriseTime));
                        newWeatherDaily.MoonPhase = moonPhase;
                        newWeatherDaily.SunsetTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(sunsetTime));
                        newWeatherDaily.PrecipType = precipType;
                        newWeatherDaily.TemperatureMin = temperatureMin;
                        newWeatherDaily.TemperatureMax = temperatureMax;
                        newWeatherDaily.ApparentTemperatureMax = apparentTemperatureMax;
                        newWeatherDaily.ApparentTemperatureMin = apparentTemperatureMin;
                        newWeatherDaily.TemperatureMinTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(temperatureMinTime));
                        newWeatherDaily.TemperatureMaxTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(temperatureMaxTime));
                        newWeatherDaily.ApparentTemperatureMinTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(apparentTemperatureMinTime));
                        newWeatherDaily.ApparentTemperatureMaxTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(apparentTemperatureMaxTime));
                        newWeatherDaily.DewPoint = dewPoint;
                        newWeatherDaily.Humidity = humidity;
                        newWeatherDaily.WindBearing = windBearing;
                        newWeatherDaily.WindSpeed = windSpeed;
                        newWeatherDaily.Visibility = visibility;
                        newWeatherDaily.Pressure = pressure;
                        newWeatherDaily.CloudCover = cloudCover;
                        newWeatherDaily.BlobUri = blobUri;
                        if (isForecast == true)
                        {
                            newEntities.WeatherDailyForecasts.Add(newWeatherDaily);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            newEntities.WeatherDailies.Add(newWeatherDaily);
                        }
                        int result = await newEntities.SaveChangesAsync();
                        return result;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return 0;
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm wracking my brain and can't figure out which line is actually throwing the exception, or how to reason about this. Any thoughts?

Comment: If in your tests it has the data then when it fails it most likely doesn't

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Can you debug and secure that `responseJson.daily.data[0]` is not null?

Comment: Well, when you debug its actually running right? If you do step by step is it actually throwing anywhere? Because you say there is data but usually when getting data from somewhere else and you have a null-pointer the data is not there

Comment: responseJson.daily.data[0] is not null-it is this (in this particular case):
{
  "time": 1504558800,
  "summary": "Clear throughout the day.",
  "icon": "clear-day",
  "sunriseTime": 1504581396,
  "sunsetTime": 1504627207,
  ...
  "apparentTemperatureMax": 31.6,
  "apparentTemperatureMaxTime": 1504605600
}

Comment: Check DarkSky.cs lines 434, 461 and 205 (and maybe some lines +/-) if there is something that *could* be `null`. (`Console.WriteLine` also counts if you are writing something that could become null).

Comment: All those lines are in catch statements, like this:
catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }

Except for line 434, which is something I added while trying to debug, and looks like this:

if (responseJson.daily.data[0] != null)

Comment: I dont see any runtime binding in this code. could you share the code for "DailyBreakDown" and what is the type of responseJson ?
 DbMgr.DarkSky.d__9.MoveNext() suggests that the error happens while performing the for loop

Comment: @Gurpreet thanks, done.

Comment: I think in the first comment epicKip meant that since you have no control over the incoming data, while you are debugging the outsource could be fine but it may be failing to send json at random times during the day (timeouts...etc.). Maybe you can log the incoming json with timestamp so you can check what the server has sent in case of an exception.

Comment: @mcy I'm running this code locally to try to debug and it seems that the error is consistent. I will contact the API provider and check.

Comment: Remove the try catch so you can actually see where it fails